# className={`mt-[${headerHeight}px]`} working occasionally in NextJS Template

Tags: tailwind-css, next.js13

**template.tsx**

```
'use client';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Template({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const [headerHeight, setHeaderHeight] = useState(133);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateHeaderHeight = () => {
      const headerElement = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];
      if (headerElement) {
        const height = headerElement.offsetHeight;
        setHeaderHeight(height);
      }
    };
    updateHeaderHeight();
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateHeaderHeight);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', updateHeaderHeight);
    };
  }, []);

  return <main className={`mt-[${headerHeight}px]`}>{children}</main>;
}
```

**Header.tsx**

```
<header className='fixed top-0 left-0 w-full bg-green-500 flex items-center justify-between p-2.5 px-[1.875rem] md:px-[1.875rem] lg:px-[4.1rem] md:py-6 lg:py-[2.5rem] z-10'>

...

</header>
```

Here I am trying to dynamically set the top margin of the  tag but it does not work after the initial load of the page. It only works after make some random changes to `mt-[${headerHeight}px]`. After that, even if I revert the changes, I get desired results. I want to resolve this bug and always get the appropriate margin.
It works if I change it to
`return <main style={{ marginTop:` ${headerHeight}px `}}>{children}</main>;`
but this is clearly an inappropriate way. Solutions?

"next": "14.1.0",
"tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind does not support dynamic classes. [Official DOC](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

Don’t construct class names dynamically

```
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
```

Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:

```
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
```

Tailwind can not meet your needs, you could set `Style` instead.